# Custom Spring cloud application - Kafka embeddedheader issue

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to build a custom transformer application using the guidelines provided here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#streams-dev-guide

I have started kafka on my windows machine.
I have http source running on windows machine it writes to destination transformData.
**Command**: `java -Dserver.port=8123 -Dhttp.path-pattern=/data -Dspring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=transformData -jar http-source-kafka-10-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar`

I have transform application running that reads input from transformData and outputs to destination transformedData
Command
`java -Dserver.port=8090 -Dspring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=transformData -Dspring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=transformedData -jar transformer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I have log sink running that reads from destination transformedData
Command
`java  -Dserver.port=8888 -Dspring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=transformedData -jar log-sink-kafka-10-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar`

Problem:
When I try to send this curl request:
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":"1", "temp":"400"}' http://172.20.24.47:8123/data`

On the custom Transformer console I see errors:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized
>   token '▒': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source:
>   (byte[])"?
>                          contentType
>                                     "text/plain"originalContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8"{"id":"1", "temp":"400"}"; line: 1,
>   column: 4]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
>   ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:679)
>   ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3526)
>   ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2621)
>   ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:826)
>   ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:723)
>   ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3121)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar!/:2.9.6]
>           at org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.convertParameterizedType(ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.java:114)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>           ... 37 common frames omitted

Can any one help?

Comment: BTW, the if I just have httpsrc and logsink running then the curl works fine. Wondering if need to set some consumer properties or producer properties to set headerMode=raw

Answer (score 1):

I got this to finally work. When building the custom application using the Spring initializr instead of selecting 2.0.4 release as starter I reverted back to 1.5.15 Release. Now I have no more need to pass properties on the subscriber end that is the custom app and the logger sink app  using headerModes set to embeddedHeaders.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using Spring Cloud Stream 2.0.0.RELEASE, but your app is 1.3.x. Can you set `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode` to `embeddedHeaders` in the processor app where it is failing? In 2.0, the default is not to embed headers as Kafka supports it out of the box. However, in versions prior to 2.0 (which is used by 1.3.x apps), the default is to embed the headers. You need to explicitly set that when using that combination.

Comment: Ok tried this. Now the processor app is invoked with the following command.java -Dserver.port=8090 -Dspring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=transformData -Dspring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=transformedData  -Dspring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.headerMode=embeddedHeaders -jar transformer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: now on the log sink console2018-08-02 15:07:59.964 ERROR 18252 --- [           -L-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder    : Could not convert message: 7B2273656E736F725F6964223A2231222C2274656D705F76616C223A22333030227D

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 36
        at java.lang.String.checkBounds(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeaderUtils.oldExtractHeaders(EmbeddedHeaderUtils.java:154)